# How to do count fuction inside MAX()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

- medic (idm(PK), name, address, salary)
- consult (idm, idp, data)
- pacient (idp, name, date, sex)

I want to select the medic that has done more consults to females. How can I do this?

I believe I need to do COUNT of the consults and select the MAX count possible, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using SQL server, sorry

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results (as formatted text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `MAX`, you just need a `TOP (1)`.

You can either do this in an apply:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  m.idm,
  m.name,
  m.address,
  m.salary
FROM medic m
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT numConsults = COUNT(*)
    FROM consult c
    JOIN pacient p ON p.idp = c.idp
      AND p.sex = 'F'
    WHERE c.idm = m.idm
    GROUP BY ()
) c
ORDER BY
  c.numConsults DESC;
```

Or as a normal join

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  m.idm,
  m.name,
  m.address,
  m.salary,
  numConsults = COUNT(*)
FROM medic m
JOIN consult c ON c.idm = m.idm
JOIN pacient p ON p.idp = c.idp
  AND p.sex = 'F'
GROUP BY
  m.idm,
  m.name,
  m.address,
  m.salary
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC;
```